# How to write trigger for example base

Tags: mysql

I must write a trigger that locks a user account if the number of failed login attempts exceeds 3 but completely don't know how to do :/ Please help on this example.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myAplicaction;
USE mojaAplikacja;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authorization(
         idUzytkownika INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
         login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
         password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
         liczbaNieudanychProb SMALLINT,
         czasOstatniegoLogowania TIMESTAMP,
         kontoZablokowane BOOLEAN
     );

     INSERT INTO Autoryzacja SELECT NULL, "jkowalski", SHA2('pies', 256), 1, NULL, FALSE;
     INSERT INTO Autoryzacja SELECT NULL, "mnowak", SHA2('kot', 256), 1, NULL, FALSE;
     INSERT INTO Autoryzacja SELECT NULL, "kzablocki", SHA2('ptak', 256), 1, NULL, FALSE;
     INSERT INTO Autoryzacja SELECT NULL, "lhostman", SHA2('ryba', 256), 1, NULL, FALSE;
```

Comment: "Locking" of a user account is business logic that really doesn't belong in the database layer.

Comment: Could you expand on what you're exactly needing? A trigger is used whenever a table is altered in any way. If there's a table that contains login attempts, please provide it, as the trigger would need to be placed on that table in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this trigger:

```
create trigger tr_upd_Autoryzacja before update on Autoryzacja for each row
begin
    if (new.liczbaNieudanychProb > 3) then 
        set new.kontoZablokowane := true;
    end if;
end;
/
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3396e/1)

Comment: Did this answer your question, or could you give some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider if this user will be released after some time. So, you must save the datetime of the user locking too, and consider a time to live for it.

I would recommend you to use a log-table where you will log all login failed attempts. Than, create a trigger on each insert, and count the login attempts on last minute. If it exceeds 5 tries, you run an update on user table, setting blocked = 1 and blocked_until = now() + 5 minutes.

On your login script, you must build a sql query like:

```
select userid from users where login = 'userlogin' and password = 'password' and active = 1 and (blocked = 0 or blocked_until < now() )
```